# Criteria for existence of iid common factors

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, time-series, regression-analysis

Let $x$ be a $n$-dimensional random vector with $Cov(x)=I_n$. Under which conditions do exist a $l$-dimensional $(l\leq n)$ random vector $z$, a matrix $\Gamma\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times l}$ and a $n$-dimensional random vector $\epsilon$ such that the following conditions are satisfied:

1) $x=\Gamma z+\epsilon$

2) The elements of $z$ are iid, the elements of $\epsilon$ are iid and the elements of $z$ and $\epsilon$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

If 1) and 2) hold, then $$\text{Cov}(\Gamma z + \epsilon) = \text{Cov}(\Gamma z) + \text{Cov}(\epsilon) = \Gamma \text{Cov}(z) \Gamma^\top + \text{Cov}(\epsilon)$$
by independence of $z$ and $\epsilon$.
Since the elements of $z$ are i.i.d. and the elements of $\epsilon$ are i.i.d.,
both covariance matrices $\text{Cov}(z)$ and $\text{Cov}(\epsilon)$ are multiplies of the identity, specifically $\text{Var}(z_1) I$ and $\text{Var}(\epsilon_1) I$.
So,
$$\text{Cov}(\Gamma z + \epsilon) = \text{Var}(z_1) \Gamma \Gamma^\top + \text{Var}(\epsilon_1) I.$$

If this equals $I$, then one of the following must happen.

- $\Gamma$ has orthonormal rows (so that $\Gamma \Gamma^\top = I$) and $\text{Var}(z_1) + \text{Var}(\epsilon_1) = 1$, or
- $\text{Var}(z_1) = 0$ (i.e. $z_1$ is a constant) and $\text{Var}(\epsilon_1)=1$.

$\Gamma\Gamma^\top = I$ is only possible if $l \ge n$, so given your restriction $l \le n$ we must have $l=n$ in the first situation.

On top of all these constraints on $z$, $\Gamma$, $\epsilon$, I still don't think this is enough to guarantee existence. (For instance, I have not checked that $E[x] = E[\Gamma z + \epsilon]$.) Maybe I am not approaching the problem in the right way...

Comment: Many thanks for the ideas. So far I can only see that if $x$ is multivariate normal it works for $z=Cov(x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}x$ and $\epsilon=0$. But I thougt there might be weaker restrictions.